# Linux: Why loader finds my shared library?

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries, ubuntu-14.04

I have compiled a shared library with CMake as a sub project and the main app then links to the library. The library and application are in the same output directory somewhere under my home dir.

Because I'm on Linux I don't now understand why the loader sees my library.

When I check libs with ldd everything is ok. However, I was under the impression that I have to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH so that my application can load the shared lib from the same directory. But I haven't set it and it still works. Why?

Comment: Probably CMake set up the makefiles to add an option for the linker to tell it where the shared library is. Search for the `ld` option `--rpath`.

Comment: Was that .so linked in using `-L` and `-l`?  The alternative is to link in a .so directly using its full path and name.  If CMAKE linked the .so using its full path and name, there is no search at load time.  It just uses that same full path and name.

Comment: @JSF No, it seemed to use -Wl,-rpath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps your build process is setting `RPATH` inside your executable to look for the library in the same directory.  To test this, try moving the executable to a different directory and see if you can run it (or `ldd` it) then.

You can also check for `RPATH` in an executable in either of these ways:

```
readelf -d the-exe | grep RPATH
objdump -x the-exe | grep RPATH
```

For more on this, see here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22926/where-do-executables-look-for-shared-objects-at-runtime

Comment: Or run `readelf -d ./thebinary |grep RPATH`. automake/autoconf typically embeds RPATH automatically so you can easily run the compiled application from within the project folders, and re-links it to exclude the RPATH during `make install` (if the DESTDIR is in a common place where RPATH isn't needed) I suspect CMake have similar automagic intelligence.

Comment: @nos: Thanks, I added your `readelf` idea along with an `objdump` alternative.